# My INNER JOIN SQL command yields no results

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, inner-join

I try to make a query using the INNER JOIN command and it executes successfully but it yields no results.
Here is the SQL code I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM `departament` INNER JOIN `fakultet` 
ON "departament.#ID_Fakultet"="fakultet.ID_Fakultet"
```

And here are the tables
the departament table:

[image]

the fakultet table

[image]

Comment: "departament.#ID_Fakultet" is a string. "fakultet.ID_Fakultet" is also a string. It's the equivalent of saying "ON 'yes' = 'no'"

Comment: @Strawberry Sigh...another wasted cell phone edit

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, but awesome thumbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you write in double (" ") or single (' ') quotes it will take as string.

```
SELECT * FROM `departament` INNER JOIN `fakultet` 
    ON departament.`#ID_Fakultet`=fakultet.`ID_Fakultet`
```

can you run this query?

Comment: Typically we don't answer typo questions because they don't help anyone.

Comment: Ok next time i will tack care about it